# What's the quickest (free) way to get keys in Ancient Egypt?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I've played around in Ancient Egypt for a while and I've noticed all these extra paths hidden behind key gates. Unfortunately, I don't have enough keys to open all the gates.  Without purchasing anything, what's the fastest way to mine more Egypt keys?

Comment: grind egypt levels

Comment: Don't you need 15 stars to unlock the star gate?  Keys are used to unlock branching paths.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - Oh dear, you're right. The star gate had a keyhole, so I thought it needed keys. I didn't even think about the stars...  I am a silly goose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keys drop randomly so there isn't a fastest way other than keep playing levels. You may optimize your gameplay by trying to get all the stars, and once you've got them all you'll even have some leftover keys.

Comment: Source? I haven't found any yet replaying the levels. The only ones I've found after getting to the star gate were from the Treasure Yeti and one in the Doom Pyramid.

Comment: Nevermind, I just got a key as a random zombie drop!

Answer (score 1):

Set your day time 2 days after in SETTINGS DATE AND TIME and a treasure yeti should appeared because it's programmed to spawn roughly every day.Just fight him and collect the lunch box which MAY contain 3 keys, if not then there will be 1000 coins