# How frequently do the zombies drop keys?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

Someone mentioned in this [Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129095/whats-the-quickest-free-way-to-get-keys-in-ancient-egypt) that you can get keys when zombies randomly drop them on any level.

Is there an estimate of just how frequently this happens? (e.g. what's the probability)

Is the frequency dependent on the zombie type you kill or the level?

Answer (score 1):

Keys were removed from the game in December 2013, as part of the v1.7 update. ([Source](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Key))

Answer (score 0):

I think it is rigged. The keys drop relatively rarely in a level until you need them. After you have opened all the locks, they appear much more frequently.

Comment: Did you do specific experiments to confirm that? (e.g. count how many keys before and after per level/zombie")?

Answer (score -3):

20 in 50 chance,  most likely when yeti zombie appears

Comment: 2 in 5 chance is very high. I do not see a key dropping twice every 5 levels, let alone every five zombies.